# Регулярное выражение - Найти все одиночные переносы строки и добавить начало строки

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Помогите составить регулярное выражение которое будет:
искать в тексте *одиночные* переносы строки (\r или \x0d) и заменять его на \r\n или \x0d\x0a
Но загвоздка в том, что нужно исключить из поиска перенос за которым идет новая строка.

Ну или на примере слов:
A**S**SIGN **S**E**S**SION **S**MIRNOFF
нужно найти только буквы S за которым не идет буква I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Необходимо использовать опережающую проверку.

Статья на [хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/159483/) об этих проверках.

**Look-behind** — ретроспективная проверка «смотрит» назад.
**Look-ahead** — опережающая проверка «смотрит» вперед.

Синтаксис:

```
(?<=pattern) положительное look-behind условие
(?<!pattern) отрицательное look-behind условие
(?=pattern)  положительное look-ahead  условие
(?!pattern)  отрицательное look-ahead  условие
```

Для строки "A**S**SIGN **S**E**S**SION **S**MIRNOFF" решение будет

```
S(?!I)
```

Comment: Спасибо!  Кто бы мог подумать про "Утверждение отрицательного просмотра вперед нулевой ширины" и всякие "ретроспективные проверки"... А задача казалась простой